# Linux permissions for services

Tags: linux, permissions, services, daemon

How do permissions work for services in Linux? I already know that I can set `read`, `write` and `execute` permissions for files and directories with `chmod` each for `owner`, `group` and `other users` but how do permissions work for a running service? How can I see what permissions a service has on particular files/directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A service is bound by regular permission restrictions. It all depends on what user the service runs as. Services are just regular processes that are always running.

For example,

```
$ ps aux | grep apache2
root      2845  0.0  0.2  75596  4508 ?        Ss   Sep06   0:19 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25608  0.0  0.1  74428  2232 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25609  0.0  0.1  75596  2288 ?        S    Sep09   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25610  0.0  0.4 2003664 8436 ?        Sl   Sep09   0:37 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25611  0.0  0.4 2003788 8584 ?        Sl   Sep09   0:36 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25700  0.0  0.4 2003648 8528 ?        Sl   Sep09   0:36 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

You can see that the service is run by `root` and by `www-data`. Apache uses the `root` process only for binding to port 80 (or whatever port you've configured). Recall that binding to ports < 1024 requires you to be root.

For security, though, Apache hands off all request processing to processes that run as `www-data`. What these processes can access is up to you. If your file permissions in your document root don't permit `www-data` to access the files, Apache won't be able to serve them.

This is the same for any service; typically they have

- A process running as `root` (if they must bind to a port < 1024; not all services have a `root` process, though) which delegates tasks to the less-privileged user
- A process running as a user they created (`bind` for BIND, `www-data` for Apache, `proftpd` for proftpd, etc.). Keep in mind that the names of these vary by system (Apache sometimes runs as `apache` or `apache2` instead of `www-data`).

Some processes run as `nobody` instead of as a specific user, though. This can be a bad idea, but it depends on the process and what it's doing.

These are just general rules; some processes even run entirely as root (such as `sshd`, although it will use a user process when someone connects). Use `ps aux` to see what user a process is running under.

Comment: Thanks man! That's exactly what I looking for...another question, how can i change the user for a process?

Comment: @Gigitsu that depends on the service; for Apache, for example, you need to change `APACHE_RUN_USER` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP`. You'll have to check the documentation for the service you're looking at, since it's different for each one.

Comment: Well, sorry to digress, but I notice that haproxy can run as haproxy(not as root), and bind tcp 80 port. How does this achieve? Any enlightenment?

Comment: @kiiwii https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443